# Update SQL Query to Remove all Characters after left paren sysbol

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, symbols

I have a table in a SQL Server database called `STATS`. In the `STATS` table I have a column named `Agent`. I want to update every value so everything before "(" is removed.

```
AGENT
---------------
SDave(55555)
TMICHAEL(66666)
JJORDAN(232323)
```

I want to update table so it only displays as

```
AGENT (COLUMN NAME)
------------------
SDave
TMICHAEL
JJORDAN
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which database you are using?

Answer (score 1):

try this `UPDATE table
SET table = LEFT(agent, CHARINDEX('(', agent) - 1)
WHERE CHARINDEX('(', agent) > 0`

Comment: Thank you!  feedback left but not showin as my rep is not high enough yet.  People give Mango some love for me!

Answer (score 0):

In sql-server you can use `SUBSTRING()` AND `PATINDEX()`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(AGENT,1,PATINDEX('%(%',AGENT)-1) Agent
FROM STATS S
```

In MySql you can use SUBSTRING() and `INSTR()`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(AGENT,1,INSTR(AGENT,'(')-1)  Agent
FROM STATS S
```